# The Patchwork theme's patchwork_posted_on() method doesn't work on the latest Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I just upgraded a blog I host to `WordPress 3.9.1`. On that blog, I use the [Patchwork theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/patchwork). Following that, the blog stopped working. I couldn't see any serverside PHP errors - that's likely due to a misconfiguration of my logging. On the browser side, I could see I was getting HTTP 500 with Chrome's Developer Tools.

I eventually realized the problem came from this method in the [Patchwork theme](http://wordpress.org/themes/patchwork):

```
function patchwork_posted_on() {
    printf( __( 'Posted on <a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="bookmark"><time class="entry-date" datetime="%3$s" pubdate>%4$s</time></a><span class="byline"> by <span class="author vcard"><a class="url fn n" href="%5$s" title="%6$s" rel="author">%7$s</a></span></span>', 'patchwork' ),
        esc_url( get_permalink() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_time() ),
        esc_attr( get_the_date( 'c' ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_date() ),
        esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ),
        esc_attr( sprintf( __( 'View all posts by %s', 'patchwork' ), get_the_author() ) ),
        esc_html( get_the_author() )
    );
}
```

I haven't done a lot of PHP in a while so I'm struggling to see what's wrong with it. Considering it worked with Wordpress 3.9.0 and it doesn't work anymore, I am tempted to say that one of the methods here has been deprecated.

Does anyone have an idea?

--- EDIT ---

I didn't write the theme and it hasn't been updated in a very long time so the issue must come from a change either in wordpress that breaks the theme or in another plugin I could have updated.

Also, the error that I get is that the post page gets generated all the way up to the title and then when it's about to print *Posted on ... By ...* it dies. That is in fact what led me to investigate whatever was being called at that point.

Thanks.

Comment: This information might help: Downloaded Patchwork version 1.3 to Wordpress 3.9.1. Using PHP 5.3.8 and 5.4.28 did not have any problem running the theme with default pages and configuration. Besides a warning in PhpStorm about the `pubdate` attribute, the function you mention does not have any error.

Comment: Do you re-declare this function anywhere else in the theme? and how did you deduce it was coming from that function? What page types is it not working on? What version of wordpress did you upgrade from?

Comment: How/why did you determin that the issue comes from pathcwork_posted_on() ? do you have Silence Deprecated PHP Errors on or off in your php settings?

Comment: Because when I commented the contents of that method with /* and */ then everything worked again. I have another issue with my php.ini. It looks fine but the error logs are not being produced, but that's for a separate SO question (or just investigation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, `get_the_date()` is the one creating the problem. I can still find pages at wordpress describing it but it is not in the [function index](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference).

I updated my code to use `get_the_time` only:

```
echo __('<!--:en-->By <!--:--><!--:fr-->Par <!--:-->'.'<a class="url fn n" href="'.esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ).'" title="Voir tous les articles de '.esc_html( get_the_author() ).'" rel="author">'.esc_html( get_the_author() ).'</a><!--:en--> on '.get_the_time('F j, Y').'<!--:--><!--:fr--> le '.get_the_time('j F Y').'<!--:-->' );
```

BTW, since then, I had the issue on another blog - separate wordpress on the same PHP server.

Comment: `get_the_date()` definitely still exists, please check out the [code reference](http://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/). I've updated the Codex page to reflect that. WordPress generally does not remove public functions in a backwards-incompatible way.

Answer (score 4):

You're likely hitting the PHP memory limit.

There's nothing wrong with `patchwork_posted_on()` function, it does not use any deprecated methods.

Comment: Hi, I narrowed down the issue to get_the_date(). If I use that method, then PHP just dies. I still don't get any stack trace or error messages which is frustrating. If I comment out the get_the_date() method then it works fine.

Comment: `get_the_date()` is a filterable function, which means a plugin or theme can alter its output, possibly breaking it. Does the issue still happen with all plugins disabled and a default theme (Twenty
 Fourteen or Twenty Thirteen) activated?

Comment: The "guilty" use of 'get_the_date()' happens within a specific template. I actually do not know why the template author uses it since I can very well use get_time and that works just fine.